# Friend array recursive

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to do the friend array recursively, one array is friend of another one if `arr1[i][j] = arr2[j][i]` so I tried to do it recursively but I only change the first row, the other keeps the same, I have to do it only with 1 array I mean I can't create two the changes I guess have to be on the same array, I did this :

```
int friendArray[][] = {
    {1,2,3,4},
    {5,6,7,8},
    {9,10,11,12},
    {13,14,15,16}
};

friendArrayRecursive(friendArray, 0,0);


private static void friendArrayRecursive(int[][] arr, int row, int col){
    if(row < arr.length){
        if (col < arr[row].length) {
            arr[row][col] = arr[col][row];
            friendArrayRecursive(arr, row, col + 1);
        } else {
            friendArrayRecursive(arr, row + 1, 0);

        }
    }
}
```

But the output instead of be :

```
1 5 9 13
2 6 10 14
3 7 11 15
4 8 12 16
```

is

```
1 5 9 13 
5 6 10 14 
9 10 11 15 
13 14 15 16
```

How can I save the other value to change the 2 for the 5 etc...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As nhouser9 said, you need to swap the values by using a temporary variable. Then of course, if you go through all cells, the swap will happens twice and thus it will be cancelled. So you need to go through half of the array only using the comparison (col < row).

```
private static void friendArrayRecursive(int[][] arr, int row, int col){
    if(row < arr.length){
        if (col < row) {
            int temp = arr[row][col];
            arr[row][col] = arr[col][row];
            arr[col][row] = temp;
            friendArrayRecursive(arr, row, col + 1);
        } else {
            friendArrayRecursive(arr, row + 1, 0);    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me why you changed the col < arr[row].length to col<row please?

Comment: By using this comparison, the algorithms goes through the cells in the bottom-left triangle when col < row.

Comment: I debuged it and in the end it join only in else statement it's that good? is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `if` conditions to

```
if(row >= arr.length)
  return;
if(col >= arr[row].length)
  return;
if(row < col) {
    int temp;
    temp = arr[row][col];
    arr[row][col] = arr[col][row];
    arr[col][row] = temp;
    friendArrayRecursive(arr, row, col + 1);
 } else {
    friendArrayRecursive(arr, row + 1, 0);
 }
```

Comment: What if condition

Comment: there you go @Stuart2041

Comment: no, keeps the same I can change the 2 for 5 but then I loose the 2

Comment: you are just copying one cell to another. what you need to do is swap

Comment: tried it, but at the time you do the row 1 they'll swap again